# Who opens pipes in USB communication?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

I just need to know who in the USB communication must open the pipes. Endpoints are already configured, descriptors was sent and now there should be a process of pipes opening (between correct endpoints). Who opens these pipes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all in the USB spec, of course.

In USB, pipes aren't really "opened".  During configuration, the device tells the host what endpoints it can talk what protocol over.  Then host then sends data to or request data from endpoints as it sees fit.

For details, read the USB spec.